# coffeescript existential function operator else statement?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

In coffee script, using the existential operator on a function like so:

```
myFunc?()
```

compiles to

```
typeof myFunc === "function" ? myFunc() : void 0;
```

Is there a way to elegantly define what would go in place of "void 0"? or must I write it all out instead of using the original notation?

Comment: I guess such shortcuts are handy, but it would be better if Coffeescript re-wrote it in the far more common form: `if (typeof myFunc == 'function') myFunc();`, which is fewer characters as well. Of course that is a pretty ordinary test anyway and should never be applied to host objects because it will fail sometimes. And there is absolutely no need for `===` in the test, `typeof` returns a string always (per ECMA-262), so the Type will always be consistent.

Comment: @RobG That's not a general solution because it is common to use the return value of the function-existential.  This is why ternaries are preferred in many cases when they produce seemingly superfluous code.

Comment: You've lost me. The test I propose is exactly the same as the one for the ternary expression. It's preferred (by me at least) because it does exactly what is expected and doesn't need superflous code to clean up afterward, which hints that the ternary form is inappropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add another existential operator:

```
x = f?() ? 'pancakes'
```

That won't work if `f()` returns `null` or `undefined` but it will do the Right Thing if `f()` returns `false`. For example:

```
f = 'not a function'
console.log f?() ? 'pancakes'
# pancakes

f = -> 'is a function'
console.log f?() ? 'pancakes'
# is a function

f = -> null
console.log f?() ? 'pancakes'
# pancakes

f = ->
console.log f?() ? 'pancakes'
# pancakes

f = -> false
console.log f?() ? 'pancakes'
# false
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/f6yvN/1/

So you can get close to what you want and that might be close enough depending on what sort of things you're expecting the function to return.

Comment: Please no. The conversion to a ternary expression is silly enough, please don't compound it. Note that `typeof obj == 'function'` will return false for some callable objects in some environments (e.g. objects implemented as ActiveX objects in IE, such as XMLHttpRequest objects). `typeof` can return anything for host objects.

Comment: @RobG: I think you're complaining to the wrong guy. If IE doesn't behave sensibly then you'd wrap it so that it does behave like a good and responsible citizen. Do you know of any examples that don't involve IE misbehaving? I think the main intent of `?` here is to let you skip some null checking boilerplate when dealing with callbacks. I certainly have my share of hate for CS but this operator isn't part of it.

Comment: this doesn't exactly work the way I was expecting. if i do
f?() ? console.log 'test' 
then even if f is a function i always log 'test'.

Comment: @Lactose: Only if `f()` returns `null` or `undefined`, there are possible problems as I noted. There are various ways around the problems depending on the specific circumstances.

Comment: @mu—comments are for everyone. Typeof tests on host objects should not be used becase they are not required to conform to ECMA-262 (they can even throw errors), so expecting them to do so is not sensible. How do you propose to distinguish callable host objects that return 'function' and those that don't?